# What is a polynomial $(a+bx)^8 = 1$ where $x^2+1=0$ and $a,b \in \{0,1,2\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is a polynomial $(a+bx)^8 = 1$ (and powers less than $8$ are not $1$) where $x^2+1=0$ and $a,b \in \{0,1,2\}$?

It seems that $(x+1)^6=8$. So that isn't it.

Just trial an error or are their any tricks to this? Any hints are greatly appreciated?

Comment: Are you working, e.g., modulo $3$? There is no solution if the coefficients $\{0, 1, 2\}$ are real.

Answer (score 1):

We must have, by norm multiplicativity, $(a^2+b^2)^2=1$, hence, since $a$  and $b$ are integers, $a^2+b^2=1$. So you have only two possibilities: $a=1, b=0$ or $a=0, b=1$, and $$a+bx=\begin{cases}1&\text{or}\\x\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

$(a+bx)^8=1$ means $a+bx=e^{\frac{i\pi(2k+1)}{4}}$

You have also $x=e^{\frac{i\pi(2p+1)}{2}}$ (since $x^2=-1$) that you can introduce into the first equation.

Looking at the imaginary and real parts of the first equation should lead you to a simple conclusion.

EDIT: you can also take advantage of the fact that powers <8 of the expression are not 1. So you have $(a+bx)^4=-1$...

But $(a+bx)^4=[a^2+b^2x^2+2abx]^2=(a^2-b^2+2abx)^2=(a^2-b^2)^2-4a^2b^2+4abx=-1$

Directly you have $x\in\mathbb{R}$ which is contradiction with $x^2=-1$...

Comment: What is the simple conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is any a,b in {0,1,2} not both zero satisfies this equation. The reason is we are in a finite field of 9 elements and once we remove 0 then we are dealing with a multiplicative cyclic group of order 8 and we finish up with Lagrange's theorem in groups

Comment: I don't understand. $(x+1)^6 = 8$, and $(x+1)^8 = 16x$. This doesn't seem to work.